# Accessing a UI thread from a non-UI thread in mvvm wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, mvvm

There is a background thread in the viewmodel. It is trying to set a usercontrol property there which is being binded to the view. In simpler terms, accessing a UI thread from a non UI thread. What are the ways to establish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for other UI control properties except for the usercontrol property. I get the error that says "the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".

Answer (score 0):

**in WPF:**

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
DispatcherPriority.Background, () => { /* UI WORK HERE */ });
```